# while loop to read from file skips first line

Tags: c

i have to read data from a file into a struct array line by line, but it skips the first line. i found somewhere else that because of the fgets and the sscanf combo the 2nd line is the first read, but i dont understand why or how i can fix this. any suggestions or pointing in the right direction would be awesome!

```
void readData(){
    char line[50];
    char name1[1][50];
    int O, M, R, W;

    input = fopen("input2.dat", "r");

    //count = 0;
    while(fgets(line, 50, input) != NULL){
        hasReadData = 1;
        sscanf_s(line, "%20s %d %d %d %d", name1[0], 50, &O, &M, &R, &W);

        for(i=0; i<200; i++){
            if(strcmp(name1[0], player_arr[i].name) == 0){
                if(O<0 || M<0 || R<0 || W<0){
                    printf_s("%s %d %d %d %d", name1[0], O, M, R, W);
                    printf_s("\tNegative value, data invalid\n");                   
                    break;
                }
                if(O<M){
                    printf_s("%s %d %d %d %d", name1[0], O, M, R, W);
                    printf_s("\tOvers less than Maidens, data invalid\n");
                    break;
                }
                if(W>10){
                    printf_s("%s %d %d %d %d", name1[0], O, M, R, W);
                    printf_s("\tWickets greater than 10, data invalid\n");                  
                    break;
                }

                player_arr[i].oversOverall += O;
                player_arr[i].maidensOverall += M;
                player_arr[i].runsOverall += R;
                player_arr[i].wicketsOverall += W;

                player_arr[i].oversLatest = O;
                player_arr[i].maidensLatest = M;
                player_arr[i].runsLatest = R;
                player_arr[i].wicketsLatest = W;
            }           
        }
    }
    fclose(input);
}
```

Comment: Post the first and 2nd line of your file.

Comment: 1) Check and report the result of `sscanf_s(line, "%20s...`. 2) post definition of `player_arr`.

Comment: My guess: The names in the file have spaces and `sscanf_s(line, "%20s %d ...` only puts the first name in `name1[0]` leaving `"%d"` to cope with the last name.  By checking with `if (5 != sscanf_s(line,...)) Announce_Error();` code would have detected that and other problems.

Comment: `sscanf` shouldn't cause you to skip a line. The source you read may have been talking about combining `scanf` with `fgets`.

Answer (score -1):

If your while is skipping first line while reading from the file then use this command inside the while loop:

`file_pointer.seekg(0,ios::beg);`

This file pointer will set your pointer to the beginning of the file.

Comment: The question is tagged `c`, so C++ streams are not available.